# Unable to increase Ag-grid row height

Tags: ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid react to add rows dynamically to the grid and have a button in one of the columns.  However I'm unable to adjust the row height and as such part of the button gets chopped off like so:
[image]

I've tried setting the row height explicitly in gridOptions
And tried getRowHeight callback

```
const [gridOptions,setGridOptions] = useState({
        rowHeight: 50,
        getRowHeight: (params) => {
            return params.data.rowHeight;
          },
```

None work.

What should i do?

Comment: Also tried resetRowHeights, that didnt work as well:
 onGridReady: (params) => {
            setGridApi(params.api);
            params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            params.api.resetRowHeights();
            window.onresize = () => {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
              };
        }